# Is there a rule of order for joining processes when using multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, subprocess

I have three Python script files (script1.py, script2.py and script3.py) and I want script1.py and script2.py to run simultaneously and script3.py to start only when script2.py is finished (script1.py doesn't have to be finished yet when script3 starts).

I have a code like this to work it out but I'm not sure if I'm doing the right stuff:

```
import subprocess
import multiprocessing

def func1(command):
    subprocess.run(command, shell=True)

def func2(command):
    subprocess.run(command, shell=True)

def func3(command):
    subprocess.run(command, shell=True)

if __name__ =='__main__':
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=func1,args=('python3 script1.py',))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=func2,args=('python3 script2.py',))
    p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=func3,args=('python3 script3.py',))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p2.join()
    p3.start()
    p3.join()
    p1.join()
```

Is it gonna work? Is there a better way to do this?
Is there a rule that I have to join them in the order as they were started?

Comment: I think you wanted `script3.py` in the p3 line

Comment: Yes, thankyou. I'll edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is going to work and there is no rule of order.

Also, you could use the same function for all three processes as they're identical, and you'll probably need to convert command to a list (`args=(['python3', 'script1.py'],)`)

Comment: So the script3 won't start until the script2 is finished, right?

Thank you for the quick answer!  - yes, the the same function should be used!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the code will function like you want. `p2.join` blocks until that process is completely finished.

IMO, this is a case where multithreading makes more sense than multiprocessing. Your subprocesses aren't really doing any work. They are just spawning another process and sleeping until it returns.

Consider this approach instead

```
import threading
import subprocess

def run_script(script_filename):
    command = f'python3 {script_filename}'
    subprocess.run(command, shell=True)

if __name__ =='__main__':
    p1 = threading.Thread(target=run_script, args=['script1.py'])
    p2 = threading.Thread(target=run_script, args=['script2.py'])
    p3 = threading.Thread(target=run_script, args=['script3.py'])

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p2.join()
    p3.start()
    p3.join()
    p1.join()
```